# How to make Jetpack compose IconButton's width to adapt children's width?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, iconbutton

I want to make an `IconButton` with text below the icon. I have tried applying those width-related methods in `Modifier` to all the `IconButton`, `Column`, `Icon` and `Text`. The code below the is closest I got. The result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmk7g.png). And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNTt1.png) is what I want to achieve.

```
@Composable
fun IconButtonWithTextBelow(
    title: String,
    @DrawableRes imageId: Int,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    IconButton(
        onClick = onClick,
        modifier = Modifier.requiredWidth(IntrinsicSize.Max)
    ) {
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = Modifier.requiredWidth(IntrinsicSize.Max)
        ) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = imageId),
                contentDescription = title,
            )
            Text(
                text = title,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

As the name `IconButton` implies, it is only for displaying `Icon`. Even if you increase the size of the container with a static size modifier, you will find that the ripple when you click it is still too small.

You can use `TextButton`, I will work fine with `Icon` + `Text`, you just need to specify `contentColor`: `IconButton` uses `LocalContentColor.current` by default, so you can use that too.

```kotlin
TextButton(
    onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
    colors = ButtonDefaults.textButtonColors(contentColor = LocalContentColor.current)
) {
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
    ) {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = imageId),
            contentDescription = title,
        )
        Text(
            text = title,
        )
    }
}
```

But the implementation of `TextButton` may change in the future, the name says only about `Text` after all.

So a better option would be to just use the `clickable` modifier on your `Column`, and maybe `padding`. The result will be pretty much the same.

```kotlin
Column(
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(10.dp)
        .clickable(
            onClick = onClick,
            role = Role.Button,
        )
) {
    Icon(
        painter = painterResource(id = imageId),
        contentDescription = title,
    )
    Text(
        text = title,
    )
}
```

Answer (score 5):

IconButton's size restricted with 48.dp so you need to implement your own IconButton. You can check source code of [IconButton](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/IconButton.kt).